# Word Processors: How to keep previous style when moving cursor position?

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer, word-processing

This is a general question about word processors, and I need an answer of some word processor, especially the tagged editors.

How to keep the previous style when moving the cursor position?

For example, in case that some bold text is written, and after it not bold text had written.

Like this: **hello** world.

After the not bold word "world" was written, the current style is not bold. After setting the cursor location in the middle of the bold word "hello", now the style changes to bold, and if a character is typed, it will be typed bold.

My question is, how to prevent the style from changing, so that after setting the cursor in the middle of the bold word, when a character is typed, it will not be bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in function in Microsoft Word that will perform the task that you have specified. A custom COM or VBA add-in routine would need to be used in order to achieve that functionality.